# Root MUSIC and solution of conjugate palindromic polynomials

Tags: radar

The root-MUSIC algorithm gives direction of arrival angles directly and avoids the computational overhead of computing the MUSIC estimator curve (see *Direction of Arrival Estimation using a Root-MUSIC Algorithm* in the Proceedings of the International Multi Conference of Engineers and Computer Scientists 2008 Vol II).

However, for a $P$ element antenna, the root-MUSIC algorithm constructs a conjugate palindromic polynomial  of degree $2(P-1)$ from the diagonals of a Hermitian matrix constructed from the noise space eigenvectors. The $2(P-1)$ roots occur in conjugate reciprocal pairs $z$ and $\frac{1}{z^*}$ by nature of the conjugate palindromic symmetry of the polynomial and their arguments give candidate DOA angles.

I'm solving this polynomial (of degree $2(P-1)$) by construction of the companion matrix and then using a general complex LAPACK eigensolver. This is obviously inefficient for two reasons:

1. the companion matrix has size $2(P-1) \times 2(P-1)$ whereas the problem is fundamentally of order $(P-1)$ and
2. I'm not able to use the constraint that the polynomial has conjugate palindromic symmetric leading to reciprocal pair roots.

Does anyone know of

1. a modification to the root MUSIC algorithm that constructs a polynomial of only degree $(P-1)$ containing just the roots inside or outside the unit circle or
2. having constructed the conventional root MUSIC polynomial of degree $2(P-1)$ is there an elegant way of factorizing it into two polynomials each of degree $(P-1)$: $$p(z)=z^{P-1}.q(z).q^*(\frac{1}{z^*})$$?